# EntityListener is not getting invoked

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes -
**Employee.java**

```
@Entity(name="EMPLOYEE")
@EntityListeners(value = { EmployeeLog.class })
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private int empID;

    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;

    public int getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(int empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeLog.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;


public class EmployeeLog implements Serializable{
    @PreUpdate
    public void logPreUpdate(Employee e) {
        System.out.println("Before database SAVE/UPDATE operation.");
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void logPostUpdate(Employee e) {
        System.out.println("After database SAVE/UPDATE operation.");
    }
}
```

I want EmployeeLog listener to be invoked on Employee class whenever Employee is updated. Problem is, my listener is not getting invoked. This is my testing code -

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Employee emp = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 1);
System.out.println("Employee :::::::::::"+emp.getEmpName());
emp.setEmpName("John Doe Modified");
session.update(emp);
System.out.println("Employee updated::::"+emp.getEmpName());


session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

I found this article related to EntityListener [EntityLIstener not called via OneToOne mapping with cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718461/entitylistener-not-called-via-onetoone-mapping-with-cascade)

In this article there is a comment-

> I suspect that the above setup doesn't work because the Application
>   object is not actually changed, so that's why @prePersist and
>   @PreUpdate don't get invoked.

Here I am changing my Employee object through setter method before calling update method but this doesn't work. When exactly listener is called? Will it be executed if I update Employee through update query?
Am I getting it completely wrong?

Comment: If you still having problems to make it work, i suggest you to create your own annotations and listen to it through aspect. Aspect can do whatever you wanted if any of method marked with your annotation is executed! It can be marked on "setId(Long id)" method when your entity is getting persisted! If you want to make it work whatever it gets updated, mark setVersion(Integer version) method (if only you are using optimistic lock)!